# In PostgreSQL, Copy Value from Row/Column Cell to Another Row/Column Cell - Same Table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to PostgreSQL.

I am trying to find a way to copy the value of a cell in one row/column, to another row/column cell.

My table currently looks like this:

| ID | date | product | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-10-01 | widget-a | 175 |
| 2 | 2022-11-01 | widget-a | 300 |
| 3 | 2022-12-01 | widget-a | 400 |
| 4 | 2023-01-01 | widget-a | 500 |

I created the 'price 2 months earlier' column.  I would like to populate it using the 'price' column like this:

| ID | date | product | price | price 2 mos earlier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-10-01 | widget-a | 175 |  |
| 2 | 2022-11-01 | widget-a | 300 |  |
| 3 | 2022-12-01 | widget-a | 400 | 175 |
| 4 | 2023-01-01 | widget-a | 500 | 300 |

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated ... Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imported your data to [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/ygkXN13s)

The following query shall work for you :

```
UPDATE mytable t1
SET "price 2 mos earlier" = t2.price
FROM mytable t2
WHERE t2.product = t1.product
AND t2.date = t1.date - interval '2 months';
```

It gives me the correct output as :

| ID | date | product | price | price 2 mos earlier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-10-01 | widget-a | 175 |  |
| 2 | 2022-11-01 | widget-a | 300 |  |
| 3 | 2022-12-01 | widget-a | 400 | 175 |
| 4 | 2023-01-01 | widget-a | 500 | 300 |

Please try to use column names as continuous one;
Like `price_2_mos_earlier` instead of `price 2 mos earlier`

Else, you have to include such column names (with spaces between column name) inside double quotes.